# Update User role for existing Users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I wrote the below code to assign a role to Users, however it creates a new role in table rather updating role for existing user.

Here is my below action method

```
public ActionResult RegisterRole(RoleMaster role, User user)
{
    using (Db db = new Db())
    {
        UserRolesMapping dto = new UserRolesMapping();

        User userDto = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username == user.Username);
        dto.Id = userDto.Id;

        RoleMaster roleDto = db.RoleMasters.FirstOrDefault(x => x.RollName == role.RollName);
        dto.RoleID = roleDto.RoleID;

        db.UserRolesMappings.Add(dto);
        db.SaveChanges();

    }
    TempData["SM"] = "Role Updated";
    return RedirectToAction("Role");
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I just changed a part of your code, if you'd like to update the user's role, actually you don't need to use DBContext.Add() method,  as you can see, this method adds a new relationship to your DB. What you need to do is fetch the user-role mapping of the user, then update its RoleID and save the change to your DB.

Here's the code sample:

```c#
public ActionResult RegisterRole(RoleMaster role, User user)
{
    using (Db db = new Db())
    {
        UserRolesMapping dto = db.UserRolesMapping.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == user.Id);
        dto.RoleID = role.RoleID
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    TempData["SM"] = "Role Updated";
    return RedirectToAction("Role");
}
```

#### Updated

If you'd like to make your method fits in these two scenarios:

1. If the user already exists, update the user's role
2. If the user doesn't exist, create a new user and assign a role

The following code may help:

```c#
public ActionResult RegisterRole(RoleMaster role, User user)
{
    using (Db db = new Db())
    {
        var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == user.Id);
        UserRolesMapping userRole = null;
        
        if(user == null)
        {
            using (DbContextTransaction transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    db.Users.Add(user);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    userRole = new UserRolesMapping
                    {
                        // the user id will be automatically filled
                        // after the user is successfully added by the code above.
                        Id = user.Id; 
                        RoleID = role.RoleID
                    };
                    db.UserRolesMapping.Add(userRole);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            userRole = db.UserRolesMapping.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == user.Id);
            dto.RoleID = role.RoleID
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    TempData["SM"] = "Role Updated";
    return RedirectToAction("Role");
}
```

Comment: Thank you this works for me, what about newly added user and I want to assign new role for him.

Comment: Then your original code works. Are you going to do both in the same method? If the user exists then update the role, if not, create a new user then assign a role to him?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, If User exist it will update role, and if does not exist then Assign new role to the user.

Comment: Okay. I just updated the code, if it helps, please mark it as an answer. Also, your question is ambiguous, please update your question and description as well. Thank you.